# rspec undefined method `sequence' for 1:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am writing a spec test in rails using rspec. One of the models I am testing has an attribute of `sequence` on it, and it is conflicting with rspec (from what I have found), but I have not been able to find a work around.

Here is my code

**lessons.rb (factory)**

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
 factory :lesson do 
    version_id 1
    add_attribute :sequence, 1 # this is the field
    name "Lesson Name"
    description "An Example Lesson Description"
    group_id 1
    content "here is some example context"
    passing_quiz_difficulty 2
    survey_id 1
    status 1
    staff_content "example staff content"
    lesson_type_id 1
  end   
end
```

**method I'm testing**

```
def second_response?(lesson)
  self.lessons.where('sequence < ?', lesson.sequence).first
end
```

**controller**

```
def show
  ...
  @part_two = true if @reveal_step.second_response?(@lesson)
  ...
end
```

**rspec stack trace**

```
Failure/Error: expect(@reveal_step.second_response?(lesson_1.id)).to eql true
NoMethodError: undefined method `sequence' for 1:Fixnum
```

This method works fine in the application, but I need to write a test for it, and I cannot find a work around with the `sequence` attribute, and I cannot leave it out because this whole method and flow of this part of the app is dependent on the `sequence` attr. Does anyone know of a workaround to use? or another way I could approach this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expectation is passing a number, `lesson_1.id`, into a method that expects a lesson. That ID does not have a `sequence` method, while lessons do.